# Where does a player's runs scored under his country's A team goes to?

Tags: cricket

As to my knowledge, there're 3 categories before a player gets into the national team. Those are, First Class, List A and t20s.

My question is, where would the runs of a player who scores for an A team (both the 4/5 days of test match, ODIs and the t20s) of his country goes into?

Do they respectively fall under First Class, List A and t20s? Like the domestic.

If anyone could shed in some light on this, would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. First Class cricket is for Tests played in Domestic, International and A team matches.
Likewise for List A in ODIs and T20 for T20s.
You can refer the stats of Virat Kohli here just to get an idea. [Virat Kohli Stats](http://www.espncricinfo.com/india/content/player/253802.html)